# Adding hardware interrupts handeling breaks the program

Tags: x86, interrupt, osdev

I'm working on a simple OS and I've managed to set up the IDT table and now I'm working on hardware interrupts and the PIC's.
In isr.c there is an array of functions and the isr handler calls the correct function base on it's index in the  and the called interrupt. While in irq.c there is basically the same thing only the array is smaller.
isr.c:

```c
ISR_handler ISR_handlerArray[256];

void CDECL ISR_regsHandler(Registers_t* regs){
    if (ISR_handlerArray[regs->interrupt] != 0){
        ISR_handlerArray[regs->interrupt](regs);

    } else if (regs->interrupt >= 32) {                                                         // this is a regular interrupt
        QemuPrintf("Unhandeled interrupt %d --> 0x%x\n", regs->interrupt, regs->interrupt);
    } else {                                                                                    // this is an exception
        QemuPrintf("Unhandeled exception %x: ", regs->interrupt);
        QemuPrintf("%s\n", g_Exceptions[regs->interrupt]);

        QemuPrintf("Registers values: \neax->%x ebx->%x ecx->%x edx->%x ebp->%x esi->%x edi->%x\n", regs->eax, regs->ebx, regs->ecx, regs->edx, regs->ebp, regs->esi, regs->edi);
        QemuPrintf("eip->%x cs->%x eflags->%x esp->%x ss->%x\n", regs->eip, regs->cs, regs->eflags, regs->esp, regs->ss);

        QemuPrintf("Interrupt->%x, error_code->%x\n", regs->interrupt, regs->error);
        QemuPrintf("KERNEL PANIC!!\n\n");
        CLI();
        HLT();
    }
}

void ISR_RegisterHandler(i32 isr, ISR_handler handler){
    ISR_handlerArray[isr] = handler;
}
```

irq.c:

```c
#define PIC_OFFSET 0x20
IRQ_Handler g_IRQHandlers[16];

void IRQ_handler(Registers_t *regs){
    u8 irq = regs->interrupt - PIC_OFFSET;
    
    if (g_IRQHandlers[irq] != 0){
        g_IRQHandlers[irq](regs);
    } else {
        QemuPrintf("Unhandled IRQ %d\n", irq);
    }
    PIC_sendEOI(irq);
}

void IRQ_init(){
    pic_init(PIC_OFFSET, PIC_OFFSET + 8);
    
    // register each hardware interrupt
    for(u8 i=0; i<16; i++){
        ISR_RegisterHandler(PIC_OFFSET + i, IRQ_handler);
    }
}

void IRQ_RegisterHandler(i32 irq, IRQ_Handler handler){
    // register the handler for the specific IRQ
    g_IRQHandlers[irq] = handler;
}
```

The OS worked fine only with isr.c, but when I added irq.c it starts breaking and not handling interrupts correctly. I also expected that IRQ0 will be called constantly because it is connected to the timer of the computer...

The full code is in my [github](https://github.com/netacohen1/the-OS-of-tetris)

Comment: In `main` you eventually do an `sti` to enable interrupts. You don't have some kind of infinite loop with a `hlt` in `main` so `main` exits and returns to `kernel_entry.asm` where you do a single `hlt`. When the first interrupt occurs at that point you start executing whatever is in memory after that `hlt` and that eventually crashed things. Either put a `hlt` in an infinite loop at the end of `main` or in `kernel_entry.asm` put the `hlt` after `call main` into an infinite loop.

Comment: I should point out that every question you have asked has been related to code you don't show. Putting links to github helps but your actual question should contain a minimal complete example by itself. I've also noticed afterwards you go back and delete the link to github from the question pretty much rendering the question useless. I highly recommend if you want to ask questions this way you consider posting your questions on the [OSDev Forum](https://forum.osdev.org/)

Comment: It's just that I usually don't know what part of my code is causing the problem so I post the part in the code that I think is problematic. But then it turns out that the problem was related to a different part of my code. So in the question itself I try to put the parts that I think is relevant, and I also post the link to github for the full picture.

Comment: I've put a `hlt` instruction at the end of `main` in an infinity loop, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I cloned your current code on Github, and at the end of `main` I put `while(1) __asm__ volatile ("hlt");` and it worked. The code didn't crash and IRQ 0 interrupts were occurring every ~18.2 times a second. It ran both in BOCHS and QEMU. If it isn't working for you possibly you made other changes to the code that are a problem. I recommend cloning the code on Github (exactly as it is), make that change and test it.

Comment: I did exactly what you say, cloned the repository, and it still doesn't work... I don't know why :(

Comment: How big is your `kernel.bin` file and are you reading enough sectors in your bootloader?

Comment: I increased the number of sectors I was reading in the bootloader and now it works. thank you so much